# How to automate setting Task Manager from its default simple view to More Details view?

Tags: windows, powershell, task-manager

I am working on automated init new machine script.
One of a boring repeated todos on new machine to switch the Task Manager to detailed view when first started.

Is there any way to automate this in script?

Comment: There are ways. What have you searched for? What have you tried?  There are rules we are told to follow:  SU: [How to ask](https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask)  SO:[Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Potential starting point: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TaskManager` and preferences but it's binary data. May that will help you some too. You just have to figure out what it's supposed to be for the preference view last saved maybe and then apply that to that key to all users at every login perhaps or to at least set as the default. If you want to enforce, once you figure it out, see what changing it, closing it, and reopening does as I think it'll make it go back to less details.

Comment: @postanote Is it a duplicate? If it is, my bad. If it is not, then worth to have a short Q/A within the stackexchange/superuser knowledge base, because it adds a value, *regardless* other unstructured databases also have a potential answer. As far as iI know that is the goal.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the `More Details` link at the bottom left-hand corner of the Task Manager GUI, then this can be easily done using Sendkeys, though Sendkeys has timing considerations or systems.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
& "$env:WinDir\System32\Taskmgr.exe"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('%d')
```

TaskManager, will always stay in the last view for which is was opened of course, so this is a one-time thing per user.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10 - 1903 and later, the following registry settings can be used:

For the current user:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TaskManager]
"StartUpTab"=dword:00000005
```

For all users:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TaskManager]
"StartUpTab"=dword:00000005
```

*Where:*

0. Processes
1. Performance
2. App history
3. Start-up
4. Users
5. Details
6. Services

Note: The value defined under HKEY_CURRENT_USER will take precedence over HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.